# Tikz How to?: Shear flow distribution around a box; Adding rectangles to lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, shapes

I am trying to illustrate the shear flow distribution around two similar boxes for my students using Tikz. The result should look like the two following examples:

[image]

From a previous try, I already have an illustration of the respective boxes. Here the one for the right box:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=1.00cm,
    y=1.00cm,
    scale=2.0,
    t1 line/.style={line width=1.0pt,line cap=butt},
    pile/.style={thin, dashed, ->, >=stealth', shorten <=4pt, shorten >=4pt},
    every node/.style={color=black}
    ]

    \def\H{0.75}
    \def\B{2}

    \coordinate (K1)  at (2*\B  , \H);
    \coordinate (K2a) at (8*\B/5, \H);
    \coordinate (K2b) at (2*\B/5, \H);
    \coordinate (K3)  at (   0.0, \H);
    \coordinate (K4)  at (   0.0,0.0);
    \coordinate (K5a) at (2*\B/5,0.0);
    \coordinate (K5b) at (8*\B/5,0.0);
    \coordinate (K6)  at (2*\B  ,0.0);

    % Linien Umfang
    \draw[t1 line] (K1.center)  -- (K2a.center) node[above, midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K2a.center) -- (K2b.center) node[above, midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K2b.center) -- (K3.center)  node[above, midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K3.center)  -- (K4.center)  node[left,  midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K4.center)  -- (K5a.center) node[below, midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K5a.center) -- (K5b.center) node[below, midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K5b.center) -- (K6.center)  node[below, midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K6.center)  -- (K1.center)  node[left,  midway] {};

    % Linien Stege
    \draw[t1 line] (K2a.center)  -- (K5b.center)  node[left,  midway] {};
    \draw[t1 line] (K2b.center)  -- (K5a.center)  node[left,  midway] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I ask myself, what is the best way to incorporate the blue rectangles? The effort to code them "by hand" seems a little too high. Is it possbile to define the blue rectangles by using the already defined nodes? Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{bluei}{RGB}{153,204,255}
\definecolor{blueii}{RGB}{51,102,255}

\newcommand\Rect[2]{%
\draw[draw=blueii,fill=bluei] #1 rectangle node {+} #2 {};
}

\def\Mult{\dfrac{M_{T}}{a^{2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\def\UL{0,0} % Upper left vertex of the rectangle
\def\LR{4,-1.5} % Lower right vertex of the rectangle

% The width (or height) of the blue rectangles
\def\hwi{15pt}
\def\hwii{7pt}
\def\hwiii{7pt}
\def\hwiv{12pt}

\coordinate (ul) at (\UL);
\coordinate (lr) at (\LR);

\coordinate (iul) at ([xshift=15pt]\UL); % Upper coordinate of left inner line
\coordinate (ilr) at ([xshift=-15pt]\LR); % Lower coordinate of right inner line

% The blue rectangles
\Rect{(iul)}{([xshift=\hwi]iul|-lr)}
\Rect{(ilr)}{([xshift=-\hwi]ilr|-ul)}

\Rect{([xshift=-\hwii]ul)}{(ul|-lr)}
\Rect{([xshift=\hwii]lr)}{(lr|-ul)}

\Rect{(ul)}{([yshift=\hwiii]iul)}
\Rect{(ul|-lr)}{([yshift=-\hwiii]iul|-lr)}
\Rect{(ilr)}{([yshift=-\hwiii]lr)}
\Rect{(ilr|-ul)}{([yshift=\hwiii]lr|-ul)}

\Rect{(iul)}{([yshift=\hwiv]ilr|-ul)}
\Rect{(iul|-lr)}{([yshift=-\hwiv]ilr)}

% The outer black rectangle with inner lines
\begin{scope}[line width=1.3pt,line cap=rec]
\draw (ul) -| (lr) -| (ul);
\draw (iul) -- (iul|-lr);
\draw (ilr) -- (ilr|-ul);
\end{scope}

% The labels and dashed lines
\path (ul) to node[gray] {$0,0461\Mult$} (lr);
\node[anchor=north east] 
  at (ul|-lr) {$0,0329\Mult$};
\node[anchor=north west] 
  at (lr) {$0,0329\Mult$};
\node[anchor=north] 
  at ([yshift=-1.7*\hwiv]$(ul|-lr)!0.5!(lr)$) (low)
  {$0,0461\Mult-0,0329\Mult=0,0132\Mult$};
\draw[dashed] ([xshift=.5*\hwi,yshift=-32pt]iul) -- (low.160);
\draw[dashed] ([xshift=-.5*\hwi,yshift=-32pt]ilr|-iul) -- (low.20);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Some comments:

Let's take the image to the right on the question. To draw this you only need to set four coordinates: two will represent a pair of opposite vertices of the rectangle and the other two will be used for the inner lines.

The following code shows this `(ul)` is the upper left vertex, `(lr)` is the lower right vertex, `(iul)` sets a coordinate for the inner left line, and `(ilr)` sets a coordinate for the inner right line; colors and some nodes and labels were added for clarity.

Notice how the perpendicular coordinate system is used to draw the inner lines (this coordiante system will also be used to draw the blue rectangles):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\def\UL{0,0} % Upper left vertex of the rectangle
\def\LR{4,-1.5} % Lower right vertex of the rectangle

\coordinate (ul) at (\UL);
\coordinate (lr) at (\LR);

\coordinate (iul) at ([xshift=15pt]\UL); % Upper coordinate of left inner line
\coordinate (ilr) at ([xshift=-15pt]\LR); % Lower coordinate of right inner line

% Show the coordinates
\foreach \coord/\pos in {ul/above left,lr/below right,iul/above,ilr/below}
  \node[label=\pos:\coord,inner sep=2pt,circle,fill] at (\coord) {};

% The rectangle
\draw[cyan] (ul) -| (lr) -| (ul);

% The inner lines
\draw[orange] (iul) -- (iul|-lr);
\draw[magenta] (ilr) -- (ilr|-ul);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Again, to draw each of the blue rectangles, you only need to specify a pair of opposite vertices, so we define a command for this:

```
\newcommand\Rect[2]{%
\draw[draw=blueii,fill=bluei] #1 rectangle node {+} #2 {};
}
```

And we use this command and the four initial coordinates to draw all the blue rectangles; for example

```
\Rect{(ilr)}{([xshift=-15pt]ilr|-ul)}
\Rect{(ul|-lr)}{([yshift=-7pt]iul|-lr)}
```

will give

[image]

In the final drawing, the blue rectangles are first drawn; then the black rectangle (so it doesn't get overdrawn by the blue ones). The last step is to use some nodes to place the labels.

Of course, the initial coordinates and the height/width of the rectangles are handled through some auxiliary commands to keep consistency.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great and a lot simpler than my plan to define all vertices individually. Now is there a way to easily incorporate the labels into your solution, like 0.0461M_T/a² exactly in the middle of the inner rectangle using relative positioning to the existing four coordinates ur, lr, ...?

Comment: @user3154817 Please see my updated answer with examples of the label placement.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you a lot. I think my students will appreciate your work.